# Gate Hinge Replacement

Tags: metal, frame

I have just moved in to a house with a back gate that has a metal frame. The hinges are the pin type with one half welded to the metal frame and one half screwed into a wooden post. The bottom hinge has snapped where it connects from the post.

Do you think it is possible for me to buy a new hinge but only replace the piece attached to the wood? I would leave the gate in place and chock it up so it didn’t move then unscrew the plate from the wood, knock the pin down and free then insert a new pin and screw it in. Does anyone know if this would work and why the top pin has no thread but the bottom rusty one does?

[image]

Comment: Usually threads might mean a homemade repair on pin hinges.  Might be why it is rusted more than the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angle grinders are really cheap now. Time to buy one. Get a metal grinding wheel and a flap disc for removing the hinge from the gate frame. And get some safety glasses and some earplugs while you're at it.

You want to remove the gate from the post and ideally lay it on a bench. Use the grinding wheel running near parallel to the hinge surface to slowly erode a bit of hinge material and erode the weld until there's no longer any material connecting the hinge and the weld. Now take a flat head screwdriver to pry the hinge material away from the gate. Work the remaining weld by moving the hinge back and forth. The hinge will eventually break off.

Now grind the welds down until they're just proud of the gate's surface. Switch to the flap disc and sand the welds away with light pressure until everything is smooth (don't push too hard, or the flap disc's flexibility will unnecessarily remove gate material during this process). The welds may have undercut into the gate, leaving a bit of a gouge. Do not grind down into the gate's material to erase these gouges. They're fine. Keep the gate as thick as possible.

Paint the shiny metal with some "cold galvanizing" spray paint to inhibit future corrosion, and give it a top coat.

Now install some new hinges, but just drill through the gate's steel and use bolts to fasten them instead of welding like last time. You'll need a drill bit that lists metal as a suitable material, but these are very reasonably priced if you don't already have a set. There are novelties like rivet nuts that will save you from having a bolt head to deal with on the other side of the hinge connections. Given the corrosion that failed the previous hinge, however, I would use hot dip galvanized bolts. If the holes in the hinges seem too small or have counter-sunk edges, then ream them with a larger drill bit.

Comment: popham thats a super detailed reply which is much appreciated. I have completed the job successfully, drilling right through and using bolts was a great suggestion as it is much more secure.

Comment: Stainless steel bolts are more expensive but tend to last longer than hot dipped galvanized. Just another option for future consideration, @Jason.

Comment: @FreeMan, HDG bolts should be good for something like 40 to 60 years.

Answer (score 0):

Its very unlikely that you will find the exact same one.  It almost looks like a custom job.

- I would just saw it off with a multi-tool if possible, else just leave it there.
- And get a new hinge.  Its not that hard to drill into metal, assuming you already have a drill.  You just need the right bit for drilling into metal.